# Load distribution of transaction in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

During load testing can we achieve different transaction rate in same flow?

For example: I have a e-commerce web based application to do the load testing and I have to design the test in order to achieve TPH as below.

a. Transaction A: Login (100 transaction/hour)
b. Transaction B: Search Product (500 transaction/hour)
c. Transaction C: Payment (300 transaction/hour)
d. Transaction D: Logout (100 transaction/hour)

Could you please help me with Jmeter element configuration also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this component from jmeter-plugins 3rd party project:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/

It allows you to control throughput which. is what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Your testing doesn't assume much load as 1000 requests per hour is less than 1 request each 3 seconds which is easily achievable either manually or using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) browser-based tests.

If for some reason you need to proceed with JMeter take a look at [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) which can limit requests execution rate to the desired value.

Example configuration:

1. Add Constant Throughput Timer as a child of the `Login` sampler.
2. Add `1.66` to the "Target Throughput" input (100 requests per hour / 60 minutes in hour)
3. Switch "Calculate Throughput based on" dropdown to i.e. `all active threads in current thread group` so the throughput setting could be shared across all threads